# Nodejs var scope difficulties

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I'm experiencing a problem with node. I'm trying to use a language detection algorithm, but I'm having trouble with scopes.

After saving the response to "langVastus" and then extracting the language to "keel", I get the right result inside the Algorithmia function, but not on the outside.

The console logs print out

```
Inside: en
Outside:
```

And the code looks like this:

```
var langVastus = "";
    var keel = "";

    Algorithmia.client("simpIVxv0Ex5Xen1bVCLVXnxYpr1")
        .algo("nlp/LanguageIdentification/1.0.0")
        .pipe(input)
        .then(function(response) {
            langVastus = response.get();
            keel = langVastus[0].language;
            console.log("Inside: " + keel);
        });

    console.log("Outside: " + keel);
    res.render("lang", {keel: keel});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: which logs out first? The log from the inside or the log from the outside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I initialized the variable inside a route. Taking it outside the route fixed my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the block that you're calling "Inside", runs inside of a promise callback.

In that case the log from the outside will run before the callback is called.